# Make All fonts embedded in WinEdt

Tags: fonts, winedt

I have received the following comment from publisher on my paper:

"Please create a good pdf with all fonts used embedded. If you are unable to create a good pdf with all fonts embedded. Please see: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigfaq#a14 for help embedding Type 1 fonts."

I have two questions:
1. How could I check whether I have all fonts embedded?
2. How to make all fonts embedded in WinEdt?

Comment: If it is a PDF, see the file properties in Adobe reader. About 2,forget it. Your editor has nothing to do with this. Remember latex is independent of the editor. You may want to check the figures you are including

Comment: Full embedding of fonts is illegal for several of them; that's the reason why Adobe Acrobat itself normally does only partial embedding. However, the problem might be in the fact you're using an old TeX distribution. The most recent ones do (partial) embedding also for the "standard 35 fonts".

Comment: You can, however, enable that option on an older installation if you don't wish to update. At least, this is certainly possible with Tex Live. I imagine also with MiKTeX. (In TL, you can use `updmap` or `updmap-sys` to ensure that `dvipsDownloadBase35` and `pdftexDownloadBase14` are set true. At least, unless you have a *really* old installation, I guess, which seems unlikely.)

Comment: It is also relevant which scripts you are typesetting. I am not sure that the default embedding of subsets applies to Japanese fonts, for example, as I believe this is controlled by different options. (But I don't know much about typesetting Japanese.)

Answer (score 1):

[Summarizing the comments to get this off the unanswered list]

1. See the file properties in a PDF reader that supports this feature (e.g. Adobe Reader).
2. WinEdt has nothing to do with embedding fonts. Full embedding of fonts is illegal for several of them. Most recent compilers like pdflatex are able to do partial embedding also for the "standard 35 fonts".